# Preventing redefining existing buffer mapping

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim

I want to prevent `*noremap` command from remapping an existing sequence, but only if this sequence is local to buffer:

```
noremap a b
" Will fail, must succeed
noremap <buffer> <unique> a c

noremap <buffer> a b
" Will fail, OK
noremap <unique> <buffer> a c

noremap a b
noremap <buffer> a c
" Will fail, OK
noremap <unique> <buffer> a d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With newer vim one can use `maparg()` with fourth argument:

```
let oldmap=maparg('a', '', 0, 1)
if empty(oldmap) || !oldmap.buffer
    noremap <buffer> a c
endif
```

or, better (also supports older vim), but requires [frawor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3631):

```
execute frawor#Setup('0.0', {'@/mappings': '0.0'})
let oldmap=s:_r.map.maparg('a', 'n', 0)
if empty(oldmap) || !oldmap.buffer
    noremap <buffer> a c
endif
```